# Create Guava ImmutableRangeSet from overlapping ranges

Tags: guava

Apparently Guava's [`ImmutableRangeSet`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableRangeSet.html) cannot store overlapping ranges. This makes sense, but is there an interface to resolve/merge overlapping ranges and then put the resultant ranges into an `ImmutableRangeSet`?

Currently I'm building a [`TreeRangeSet`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeRangeSet.html), which automatically merges overlapping ranges, and passing this as an argument to `ImmutableRangeSet.builder().addAll()`. This process works, but it seems a little too indirect just to resolve overlapping ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you be more specific about your use case? I *guess* you have a collection of ranges and you're trying to create `ImmutableRangeSet` using `copyOf` method, which throws IAE in case of overlapping ranges. Let's see this test case:

```
@Test
public void shouldHandleOverlappingRanges()
{
    //given
    ImmutableList<Range<Integer>> ranges = ImmutableList.of(
            Range.closed(0, 2),
            Range.closed(1, 4),
            Range.closed(9, 10)
    );
    //when
    ImmutableRangeSet<Integer> rangeSet = ImmutableRangeSet.copyOf(ranges);
    //then
    assertThat(rangeSet.asSet(DiscreteDomain.integers()))
            .containsOnly(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10);
}
```

which fails with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Overlapping ranges not permitted but found [0..2] overlapping [1..4]
```

In this case you should use [`unionOf`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableRangeSet.html#unionOf-java.lang.Iterable-) instead of `copyOf` and it'd pass:

```
//when
ImmutableRangeSet<Integer> rangeSet = ImmutableRangeSet.unionOf(ranges);
```

Comment: Perfect! `unionOf` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!